# FreeType, some letters are missing

Tags: c++, freetype

I'm trying to introduce Text Rendering in my Game Engine, made in OpenGL. I was using FreeType and everything worked perfectly. Until today. I just run the program and some letters are missing.

If I set `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48)`, then only pqygj are missing.
If I set more then 48, than many letters are missing.

Can you help me, please?

```
Font::Font(std::string_view filePath)
    {
        FT_Library ft;
        TOMATO_ASSERT(!FT_Init_FreeType(&ft), "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library");
        
        FT_Face face;
        TOMATO_ASSERT(!FT_New_Face(ft, filePath.data(), 0, &face), "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font");

        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // disable byte-alignment restriction

        for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 128; c++)
        {
            // load character glyph 
            if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            {
                TOMATO_ERROR("ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph");
                continue;
            }
            // generate texture
            m_Chars[c].Texture = std::make_shared<Texture>(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer, GL_RED);
            
            // now store character for later use
            m_Chars[c].Size = UInt2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows);
            m_Chars[c].Bearing = UInt2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top);
            m_Chars[c].Advance = face->glyph->advance.x;
        }

        FT_Done_Face(face);
        FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
    }
```

I'm using batch rendering.

```
void Renderer::DrawText(std::string_view text, const Font& font, const Mat4& transform)
    {
        auto& ins = s_Instance;
        // activate corresponding render state  
        ins->m_Shader->Use();
        ins->m_VertexArray->Bind();

        Float scale = 0.1f;

        // iterate through all characters
        Float x = 0.0f;
        for (const auto& c : text)
        {
            auto& ch = font[c];

            Float xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
            Float ypos = - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

            Float w = ch.Size.x * scale;
            Float h = ch.Size.y * scale;

            auto color = Float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

            auto texIndex = GetTextureIndex(ch.Texture);

            if (RendererData::VertexCounter + 6 >= RendererData::MaxVertexNumber)
                Flush();

            std::array<Float4, 6> coords;
            coords[0] = Float4(xpos, ypos + h, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            coords[1] = Float4(xpos, ypos, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            coords[2] = Float4(xpos + w, ypos, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            coords[3] = Float4(xpos, ypos + h, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            coords[4] = Float4(xpos + w, ypos, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            coords[5] = Float4(xpos + w, ypos + h, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            RendererData::Vertices[RendererData::VertexCounter++] = Vertex((transform * coords[0]).xyz, color, texIndex, Float2(0.0f, 0.0f), 1.0f);
            RendererData::Vertices[RendererData::VertexCounter++] = Vertex((transform * coords[1]).xyz, color, texIndex, Float2(0.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f);
            RendererData::Vertices[RendererData::VertexCounter++] = Vertex((transform * coords[2]).xyz, color, texIndex, Float2(1.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f);

            RendererData::Vertices[RendererData::VertexCounter++] = Vertex((transform * coords[3]).xyz, color, texIndex, Float2(0.0f, 0.0f), 1.0f);
            RendererData::Vertices[RendererData::VertexCounter++] = Vertex((transform * coords[4]).xyz, color, texIndex, Float2(1.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f);
            RendererData::Vertices[RendererData::VertexCounter++] = Vertex((transform * coords[5]).xyz, color, texIndex, Float2(1.0f, 0.0f), 1.0f);

            x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale;
        }

        VertexArray::Unbind();
    }
```

Comment: You say this problem only just started? What have you changed? Are you using source control? If so can you roll back your code a couple of days?

Comment: Yes, was a good idea to roll back my code. I still can't understand, cause I didn't changed anything, but now it works again

Comment: now roll it forward a bit at a time until you find the last working revision then add in bits of the broken revision at a time until you find the problematic change

Comment: _"...cause I didn't changed anything..."_ I hear this quite often but if nothing was changed then rolling back wouldn't fix it.  Sometimes unrelated changes can expose Undefined Behaviour in existing code.  So when rolling forward from the working code keep an eye on the unchanged code as well for anything suspicious.